# Dynamic Visualforce Components - Access Pass-Through Attributes

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, html5, dynamic-vf-component

Is it possible to use html-pass-throug attributes at Dynamic Visualforce Components?

```
Component.Apex.InputField  result = new Component.Apex.InputField();
result.style = 'font-size: 9px';
result.title = 'test'; // doesn't work, because attribute is missing in InputField implementation
result.htmltitle = 'test'; // doesn't work either
result.html_title = 'test'; // doesn't work either
```

Comment: I think this attribute should be supported by InputField because most other components support it. It seems to be forgotten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it's not possible.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm

last sentence says:

> Pass-through attributes aren’t supported in dynamic Visualforce.